# Force higher version of library as referenced by NuGet dependency

Tags: nuget

Is it possible to force the installation of a higher version with NuGet in the following scenario:

- SomeLib -> references DepLib 1.0.0 via NuGet
- SomeLib NuGet package demands exact `[1.0.0]` version of DepLib in nuspec file
- MyApp -> references SomeLib via NuGet
- MyApp can't install DepLib 1.0.1 via NuGet

It gives me the following error:

> Error: Updating 'DepLib 1.0.0' to 'DepLib 1.0.1' failed. Unable to find a version of 'SomeLib' that is compatible with 'DepLib 1.0.1'.

The error is good, however, in my scenario I'm sure that DepLib 1.0.1 would work as well. Is there any way to *force* the installation of the newer library in MyApp?